# how to add an index on the mysql.slow_log table

Tags: mysql

I am running mysql.
At one moment, a lot of delayed queries are accumulated in the slow_log table.

The index cannot be created on the slow_log table, so it is always searched with full scan.
To search the slow log table, a slow query must occur again.
Is there any way to create an index on the slow_log table?

```
mysql> select @@version;
+------------+
| @@version  |
+------------+
| 5.7.33-log |
+------------+
```

```
mysql> use mysql;

mysql> SELECT table_name, engine FROM information_schema.TABLES;
+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| table_name                                           | engine             |
+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| slow_log                                             | CSV                |


mysql> SET GLOBAL slow_query_log=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create index slow_log_idx on slow_log (start_time);
ERROR 1069 (42000): Too many keys specified; max 0 keys allowed


mysql> alter table slow_log engine=MyISAM;
Query OK, 18 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 18  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> create index slow_log_idx on slow_log (start_time);
ERROR 1556 (HY000): You can't use locks with log tables.
```

Comment: Indices and triggers creation is not allowed over the tables in `mysql` database, it seems..

Comment: You can't edit mysql schema tbl.

Look at this for "log_slow_extra" => https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html

The better way is to identify the query who locks your tbl by just looking at running queries with => SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;

Comment: `ENGINE=CSV` has no provision for indexes.

Comment: I prefer to write the slowlog to a `FILE` and use `pt-query-digest` to summarize the data.  That quickly provides a list of the "worst" queries.

Comment: thank you for the reply.  When I find a way, I'll tell you again.

Answer (score 0):

Most MySQL system tables aren't indexable, so you can't index information_schema or performance_schema tables. Also, in some cases, those are actually views behind the scenes.

I can suggest two options to get your slow query log quickly analyzed:

- Copy the table to a new table, index it, and query it. For example: `CREATE TABLE my_slow_log_table AS SELECT * FROM information_schema.slow_log`
- Export the slow query log table to a file format, and analyze it quickly using free slow query log analyzers, (i.e, this [slow query log analyzer](https://slowquerylog.com/)).
  To export the table to a file, you can use this command:

`mysql -h X.X.X.X -u USER -p --raw --skip-column-names --quick --silent --no-auto-rehash --compress -e "SELECT CONCAT('# Time: ', DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%y%m%d %H:%i:%s'), CHAR(10), CHAR(13), '# User@Host: ', user_host, CHAR(10), CHAR(13), '# Query_time: ', TIME_TO_SEC(query_time), ' Rows_sent: ', rows_sent, ' Rows_examined: ', rows_examined, CHAR(10), CHAR(13), 'SET timestamp=', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time), ';', CHAR(10), CHAR(13), sql_text, ';') FROM mysql.slow_log;" > slow_queries.log`